# QGIS 3.x: Show only labels / TilesXYZ TileLayer of labels only

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, labeling, tiles

I'm using QGIS 3.6 and the TilesXYZ extension (deprecated for 3.8+) to export tilelayers of my map. I'd like to export a base layer without labels and a label layer to show on top of features.

The first part is possible, using a one-click label toggle button:

```
action = QAction(QIcon(""), "Turn labels" + "\n" + "ON/OFF", iface.mainWindow())
action.setCheckable(True)
iface.addToolBarIcon(action)

def label_control():
    for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            if action.isChecked() == True:
                layer.setLabelsEnabled(True)
            else:
                layer.setLabelsEnabled(False)
        layer.triggerRepaint()

action.triggered.connect(label_control)
# Uncomment line below if you want to remove the icon yourself,
# otherwise it will be removed automatically when you restart QGIS
# iface.removeToolBarIcon(action)
```

Is there a similar way to hide all my features but show labels?

Comment: In your feature layer, you could set the `Symbology` option to _No symbols_. This let's you show labels but not the features.

Comment: I was hoping for an easily toggle-able method, since I have about 20 layers of features. But it seems this is my only option...